# Remove rows in dataframe only if a certain condition is met using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe where I would like to remove the rows from the ['Date'] column that contains .22 and .23 only if the energy column contains a value > 0.

**Data**

```
ID  Date    type    energy
AA  Q1.22   ok      8
AA  Q2.22   n       9
AA  Q3.22   yes     8
AA  Q1.23   ok      5
BB  Q1.22   no      8
BB  Q2.22   ok      8
BB  Q3.22           0
BB  Q1.23           0
```

**Desired**

```
ID  Date    type    energy
BB  Q3.22           0
BB  Q1.23           0
```

**Doing**

```
df1 = df.drop(df[df.energy > 0].index) & df[df.Date.str.contains(".22|.23") == False]
```

**However this is actually removing the rows that contain 0**; However I wish to retain the rows that contain 0. I am still researching, any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: maybe you can try this `df[(df["Date"].str.contains(".22|.23") == True) & (df["energy"]==0)]`

Comment: if you want to select only those entries specific condition then probably it should be `( contains(pattern)==True ) & (other condition)`. 
I edited comment above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `df.drop()` to remove rows from the DataFrame.

Try this:

```
df.drop(df[(df["Date"].str.contains(pat=".22 | .23") == False) & (df["energy"] > 0)].index)
```

Comment: Hi seems not to work completely but thank you @kuldip